# Silent Push in iOS13

Tags: node.js, swift, ios13, silentpush

I gone through the apple doc, they made some changes related to silent push. We have to add `apns-push-type` in headers and also `apns-priority` should mention 5. I made these changes, normal pushes working fine but in silent case i am not receiving any push I mean `didReceiveRemoteNotification` this method doesn't get called. Also i tried without `apns-priority` in headers but no use.

```
    let headers = {
                    'apns-push-type': 'background',
                    'apns-priority': 5
                };
let sock = tls.connect(2195, server, {key: config['apkey'],cert: config['acrt'],headers}, function () {
});
```

I am using tls connection at server side, above code is server side while creating socket connection. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using the right didReceiveRemoteNotification method for background? `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`

Comment: Yes, i am using updated one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option for headers in tls, so i replaced the code with http2. Its working fine.